# Ambiguous combined usage of slot-scope and v-for on (v-for takes higher priority). Use a wrapper for the scoped slot to make it clearer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my Nuxt.js application, I use Vuetify.js. Here is the piece of code that causes me trouble:

```
<v-list dense>
  <v-hover>
  <v-list-tile
    v-for="menuItem in menuItems"
    :key="menuItem.title"
    slot-scope="{ hover }"
    :class="`elevation-${hover ? 12 : 0}`">

    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon> {{menuItem.icon }} </v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>

    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title>{{ menuItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>  

  </v-list-tile>
  </v-hover>
</v-list>
```

That triggers this error message:

> (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Ambiguous combined
>   usage of slot-scope and v-for on  (v-for takes higher
>   priority). Use a wrapper  for the scoped slot to make it
>   clearer.

The code works fine when I remove the `v-hover` component.

I read the error message and I tried to do what it suggests:

```
<template
    slot-scope="{ hover }"
    :class="`elevation-${hover ? 12 : 0}`">
    <!--
        Wrap v-list-tile-action and v-list-tile-content code here
    -->
</template>
```

But I faced other issues.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: At hover should all tiles have same class or are you going to emphasise only the one currently hovered?

Comment: I presume you should put `v-for` on `v-hover` or wrap list inside the `v-hover`.

Comment: @BillalBegueradj It seemed weird but I asked whether they all should share the same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `v-for` from `v-list-tile` to `v-hover` ([demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJNbbq)):

```
<v-list dense>
  <v-hover v-for="menuItem in menuItems">
    <v-list-tile
        :key="menuItem.title"
        slot-scope="{ hover }"
        :class="`elevation-${hover ? 12 : 0}`">

      <!-- your content -->  

    </v-list-tile>
  </v-hover>
</v-list>
```